# Low quality review queue - older questions/answers

Tags: discussion, review-queues

A number of the answers to this question:

[HTML 5 game development tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376727/html-5-game-development-tools)

Showed up in my 'low quality' review queue today, despite most of them being answered around three years ago.

I marked a number of them for deletion as being 'link only' before I noticed the date.

Are we expecting old questions and answers to show up like this?

Comment: **Are** they low quality? Don't they **add significantly** to the other answers on the question anyway? *If yes to both, down with the head.*

Comment: @Deduplicator - yep, no problem with that.  Just thought that the thinking was to generally let old questions lie and that the review queue was for newer items.

Comment: I think the discussion was about sicking the *overworked* mods on them with flags, pushing into the close queue (it's still overflowing) and useless (turd) polishing. At least as long as they did not cause problems (Mind the broken window theory). At least that was what I got from it...

Comment: Are old VLQ items being flagged manually; or does the system look for and periodically toss suspect questions/answers back into the queue for another look?

Answer (score 5):

Sure - there's plenty of cruft that gets missed initially but turns up later for one reason or another. If folks are encountering bad posts, then it's worth taking the time to fix or get rid of them.

Of course, occasionally stuff gets flushed into the queue that isn't really problematic at all; that's why there's a "Looks OK" button.

In all cases, old or new, use your best judgement.

Comment: Glad this was here and fairly recent, since just now I noticed a flood of *old* (some circa 2009) link-only answers in the LQ review queue.